# php classes - how would one go about loading a "module" object within an existing object only when its needed?

Tags: php, class, object

Ok so i have the following code setup which seems to work fine:

user handler "module":

```
class user_handler
{
    private $dbo;

    public function __construct($dbo)
    {
        $this->dbo = $dbo;
    }

    public function user_table_method()
    {
        $this->dbo->generic_db_method();
    }
}
```

the connection class:

```
class connection
{
    private $dbc;

    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbc = 'connection';
        $this->user = new user_handler($this);
    }

    public function generic_db_method()
    {
        echo '<p>doing stuff with ' . $this->dbc . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Then i can access user handler methods like so:

```
$dbc = new connection();
$dbc->user->user_table_method();
```

**My question is this:**

Would it be possible with a method in the `connection` class to create the `_user` object only when it's required?

What i'm thinking of is a method that would be used like so:

```
$dbc->add_handle('user', 'user_handler');
```

Which would create a new public property called `user` from scratch and set it as a new
`user_handler` object:

```
// in more detail
public function add_handle($name, $module)
{
    if(!isset($this->/*somehow use $name*/))
    {
        $this->/*somehow use $name*/ = new /*somehow use $module*/();
    }
}
```

..so the new way to set it up would be like:

```
$dbc = new connection();
$dbc->add_handle('user', 'user_handler');
$dbc->user->user_table_method();
```

Thanks in advance! (looking at php 5.2 and up)

Comment: You should not start your public variables or methods with an underscore. That is confusing, man.

Comment: Well i'm a php oop novice, so excuse the confusing-ness lol, please feel free to enlighten me as to what makes it so confusing? :)

Comment: Naming methods or properties starting with an underscore is generally for private methods or properties, not public. See http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function add_handle($name, $module)
{
    if(!isset($this->$name))
    {
        $this->$name = new $module();
    }
}
```

Then you would just do similar to how you were thinking:

```
$dbc = new connection();
$name = 'user';
$module = 'somemodule';
$dbc->add_handle($name, $module);
$dbc->user->user_table_method();
```

I've also renamed it from $_user to $user as I mentioned in the comment since it is public.

Comment: This would work for the one item.. it needs to take the given values and work with those though - otherwise im going to have write several `add_handle()` methods, one for every possible handler "module"

Comment: How many do you have? You could either use a switch in the add_handle() method or create multiple add_handle_* methods, one for each type.

Comment: In most cases you only need to have one database handle in a script, unless you specifically need to talk to two different databases.

Comment: ..i added a more detailed description of what add_handle() should be  doing to the question. It needs to use 2 supplied arguments. Also let me clarify what's going on - The `connection` object contains generic insert/update/delete methods. The `user_handle` contains information relative to only the user/member table and has lots of helper methods for specifically working with that table each helper method in `user_handle` makes use of the generic access methods in the `connection` object

Comment: Just take the comments out and use the variables. It should work.

Comment: Ok i have no idea what i was doing wrong earlier because i did try this and it failed. Just tried again and it worked - Now i feel like a moron :D thanks for the help/patience.. modify your answer to reflect this and i'll accept it :)

Comment: OK, edited. I think this is what you have. However, I just tried it and for some reason I'm getting an error haha...

Comment: `$this->$name = new $module($this);` - my code requires `$this` to be passed, that's not whats causing your error is it? heh.. anyhow thanks alot it's working perfectly now (for me anyways).

Comment: No, I just noticed that the error wasn't on the line I assumed it was. Silly me. I got it now.